# Can we split lines of CSV file based on two things comma and double inverted comma?

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, oracle10g

I have CSV file which contains 6 column separated by comma:

```
VendorCode, VendorName, Material, MaterialDescription, Reason, Quantity
```

I am able to retrieve data from each column except “Reason” column as it contains values in that column as:

```
Pitted, Rusty
```

( I mean comma separated values are there in that column)

(So Pitted value is inserted in “Reason “ arraylist & Rusty is inserted in “Quantity” arraylist For that particular line)

**For eg:** :

One row of csv file contains:

```
AA90,ABC LTD.,2.71E+11,ASSY/LAM`E'CE-MSSL-RINDER,"VisualCrack,B.H,Damage,Burr",330
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT :**
    **"pitty,rusted" should be treated as single string and stored in database**

i have tried this

```
while ((thisLine = myInput2.readLine()) != null)  {

    String[] str = thisLine.split(",");
    for(int j=0; j<str.length; j++) {
        switch(j) {
            case 0: DR_VendorCode.add(str[j]);//getContents()); break;
            case 1:DR_VendorName.add(str[j]);//getContents()); break;
            ....
        }

        i1++;
    }
}

for(int k=0;k<DR_VendorCode.size()+1;k++) {

    String DR_VCODE=DR_VendorCode.get(k).toString();
    String DR_VNAME=DR_VendorName.get(k).toString();
    ....
}
```

Comment: I would recommend you use a [CSV library](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java+csv) to do this parsing for you. Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: "*Also let me know how to insert backslash in database*" - please don't ask multiple questions in a single post. Research this issue separately and if you don't find any results (unlikely), then post a separate question.

Comment: @NarendraPathai: i hv gone thru many posts on this website bt useful was   String escaped = StringEscapeUtils
    .escapeCsv("I said \"Hey, I am 5'10\".\""); // I said "Hey, I am 5'10"."

System.out.println(escaped); // "I said ""Hey, I am 5'10""."""
It is also possible to invert the way for recover the original string:

String unescaped = StringEscapeUtils
    .unescapeCsv("\"I said \"\"Hey, I am 5'10\"\".\"\"\""); // "I said ""Hey, I am 5'10""."""

System.out.println(unescaped); // I said "Hey, I am 5'10"."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go ...

```
String regex = "\"[^\"]+\"|[^,]+";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(thisLine);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(thisLine.substring(m.start(),m.end()));
    // I suppose you could construct an array here rather than just printing it
}
```

Output ...

```
AA90
ABC LTD.
2.71E+11
ASSY/LAM`E'CE-MSSL-RINDER
"VisualCrack,B.H,Damage,Burr"
330
```

To handle 5th (actually any but only one) column with multiple embedded quotes ...

```
String regex = "\".*\"|[^,]+";
```

Output ...

```
AA90
ABC LTD.
2.71E+11
ASSY/LAM`E'CE-MSSL-RINDER
"VisualCrack,B.H,"Damage",Burr"
330
```

Comment: one little problem i am facing is if 5 column of csv file contain double quote in between  eg. 3721"BS3  then 3721 is stored in reason  arraylist and BS3 is stored in quantity arraylist..cud u plz edit ur regex according to that..as me nt much familiar with regex

Comment: Where? ... can you add it in this string so I can see it... AA90,ABC LTD.,2.71E+11,ASSY/LAM`E'CE-MSSL-RINDER,"VisualCrack,B.H,Damage,Burr",330

Comment: suppose AA90,ABC LTD.,2.71E+11,ASSY/LAM`E'CE-MSSL-RINDER,"VisualCrack,B.H,"Damage",Burr",330...plz see changes in this line "damage" in double quote

Comment: because user can enter comma, "",-,or any special case in 5th column...all code is running f9 except those row which contain double quotes in 5th column

Comment: should i go for encoding and decoding? to save such data in database

Comment: This regex: String regex = "\".*\"|[^,]+"; will match from the first quote it finds to the last quote it finds. So will work for data with only one field containing (many) double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you would search for patterns containing

```
"  ,   " // (make sure multiple commas could also occur)
```

i.e. double quote, 1 or more commas, double quote.

1. and replace the commas in these with a symbol or so.
2. Then replace all comma's as u please;
3. replace your symbol back to comma's.

This is partial pseudo code! I dont know how to replace patterns but you'd find out.

```
String inlineCommasReplaced = thisLine.replace( \"\,\", \"\|\"); // replace pattern "," with "|"
String outterCommasReplaced = inlineCommasReplaced.replace(",", ",,"); // Replace the comma seperated with double commas for instance
String replaceBackInlineCommas = outterCommasReplaces.replace( \"|,\", \"\,\"); // replace back the "|" to ","
String[] str = replaceBackInlineCommas.split(",,"); // split on ,,
```

Comment: but i have to save this arraylist in database

Comment: any alternative way to save this kind of CSV file data to oracle database??

Comment: You said your desired input holds the `|` symbol. That can be achieved with my pseudo algorithm. Please update your post if you wish to achieve something else. Put a comment if you think my post is not answering properly, +why. Appreciation ;)

Comment: plz try to understand my problem..i a new bie to this website..plz don't disappoint me

Comment: I added something.. do you understand the concept?

Answer (score 0):

finally sort out the problem with help of @xagyg

final code is :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
//import org.apache.commons.collections.*;
//import org.apache.commons.collections.MultiMap;
//import org.apache.commons.collections.MultiHashMap;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class readFileandPopulate{

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
      ArrayList<String> total=new ArrayList<String>();

     ArrayList<String> vcode=new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String> vname=new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String> material=new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String> mat_desc=new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String> reason=new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String> quantity=new ArrayList<String>();

      try
      {
          FileInputStream fstream1 = new FileInputStream("C:\\filesuploaded\\DEVELOPMENT_REJECTION.csv");
          DataInputStream in1 = new DataInputStream(fstream1);
          BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in1));
          String strLine1;
          while ((strLine1 = br1.readLine()) != null)  
          {
              String regex = "\"[^\"]+\"|[^,]+";
              Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
              Matcher m = p.matcher(strLine1);
              while(m.find()) {
                  total.add(strLine1.substring(m.start(),m.end()));
                  }
          }
          for(int i = 0; i < total.size(); i++)
          {
              if(i % 6 == 0)
                  vcode.add(total.get(i));
              else if(i % 6 == 1)
                  vname.add(total.get(i));
              else if(i % 6 == 2)
                  material.add(total.get(i));
              else if(i % 6 == 3)
                  mat_desc.add(total.get(i));
              else if(i % 6 == 4)
                  reason.add(total.get(i));
              else if(i % 6 == 5)
                  quantity.add(total.get(i));
          }
          System.out.println("vcode content: "+vcode);
          System.out.println("vname content: "+vname);
          System.out.println("material content: "+material);
          System.out.println("mat_desc content: "+mat_desc);
          System.out.println("reason content: "+reason);
          System.out.println("quantity content: "+quantity);      
          in1.close();

      }
      catch (Exception e)
          {     e.printStackTrace();
                System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
          }

  }

}
```